# NSURLSessionUploadTask example in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsessionuploadtask

Hi I'm using `NSURLSessionDataTask` in app to for background http call as follows,

```
 NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
```

But, I've 2 server say https://demo.demosite.com and http://214.43.45.35/ when I tried dataTaskWithRequest:request it doesn't support both server.I read [here](http://hayageek.com/ios-nsurlsession-example/) that dataTaskWithRequest:request doesn't support in background?.

`NSURLSessionUploadTask` support in background when app is not running.
Can anyone share `NSURLSessionUploadTask` callback example?

Comment: Do you want to countinue upload when app is in background?

Comment: @EktaMakadiya,hey yes, u want hit service when app is closed. it works for  single server only at a time. Could you share NSURLSessionUploadTask example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the example:

```
 NSData* data = [Your_json_string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your_url"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request =

    [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session         uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:data completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        //Perform operations on your response here
    }];

    //Don't forget this line ever
    [uploadTask resume];
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to create backgroundSession and pass the unique identifier.

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:identifier];
        sessionConfiguration.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 10;

     NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];

     NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadDataTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:multipartRequest fromFile:tmpFileUrl completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

     }];
```

Hope it will work. And if you have any question then please ask.

Comment: Completion handler blocks are not supported in background sessions. Use a delegate instead